# Can I identify an input field from inside chrome or any other apps?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to create an app which automatically inputs a previously saved password to an input field, by reading your fingerprint. For example, say I am accessing my e-mail account on the Chrome browser, and after typing my e-mail, I focus the input field for the password. I then place my finger on the sensor, and the app I want to build, which will be running as a service, identifies my fingerprint, checks that I'm using Chrome and that its current URL is the login page for my e-mail, and that the input field is the password field, and then it places my password for this account at the input field. This data is supposed to be learned by the app by logging in manually a first time. Is it possible to achieve such results? Can I read the input fields IDs inside a browser, from my app?

Comment: This might be achievable. You might want to link at this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/package-summary.html . Take a look at the FingerpintManager Class. I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with Chrome.

Comment: If you want to implement this in a web app (Running in Chrome), in don't thing you'll have access to the fingerprint scanner. If you're in a native app, you'll have access to it.

Comment: Have a look at existing password managers. Many of them register an accessibility service which allows them to access the input fields. Google LastPass to get an example.

Comment: @RomainIsnel the issue I'm most concerned about is the input fields' id visibility, the fingerprint scanning is covered. Thank you!

Comment: @vatbub I will look for that, thank you.